# Control appcache download

Tags: html, ios6, html5-appcache

I've developed an iPad web app that uses the appcache.  It's not intended to be a fully offline app but I use the appcache to store large image files so that they're not sent over 3G. Problem is when the manifest is updated the appcache updates whether the iPad is on wifi or 3G, which could be expensive.

Is it possible to have the user decide if the appcache can be updated or not? From what I've seen, this isn't possible, it all happens automatically, you just get events. But perhaps there's some trickery like writing the manifest on the fly or similar.

Using PHP on the server side if that helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

**Connection Type: Theory & Future**

There is a [draft spec of Network Information API on W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/netinfo-api/) that provides the information of the connection type (ethernet wifi 2g 3g 4g etc.), but it hasn't been implemented on any browser yet apart from:

- the stock Android browser on Android 2.2+ (not the Google Chrome browser)

  `navigator.connection.type` // Based on W3C draft, (Implemented on stock Android browser)
- and [PhoneGap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_connection_connection.md.html) which is not exactly a browser

  `navigator.network.connection.type` // on PhoneGap

Having that information in the future you could detect if the user has cellular data, then temporarily remove the src of the images and ask the user through a confirmation dialog.

You will also probably have to cancel the app cache update using:
`window.applicationCache.abort()` ([documentation](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#dom-appcache-abort))

*Reality*

Unfortunately, the Net Info API is not available (at least not widespread) at the moment, but certainly will help in the future.

**Long shot**

There is [a database](http://www.ip2location.com/ip-country-region-city-latitude-longitude-zipcode-timezone-isp-domain-netspeed-areacode-weather-mobile.aspx) that includes network speed (DIAL = dial up, DSL = broadband/cable, COMP = company/T1), but I haven't used it and I doubt it will help.

**Dynamic App Cache**

While checking into this, I tried to generate the html tag along with the manifest declaration on the fly, in order to combine it with the Network Info API but the AppCache manifest is loaded before javascript execution and is not affected afterwards.
So altering the manifest file on the fly through Javascript is not possible and data URI is not an option.

**Alternative solution**

HTML5 application cache is an untamed beast at the moment and there are [talks to improve it](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2011/10/03/improving-app-cache/). Until it changes to support more complex configurations (bandwidth level flag would be awesome), you could change perspective on the solution, although App Cache may be the best you have at the moment.

Depending on how big your images are you could rely on the normal browser cache. You could combine [localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) and far-future [expiration HTTP headers](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2007/05/high_performanc_2/). LocalStorage in order to keep track of the loaded/cached images.

- First add a far in the future date for expiration on your images HTTP headers
- On page load, remove all src from imgs
- Loop the images and check localStorage if each image was loaded in the past
- If there are images that were not loaded in the past, display a dialog confirming for the downloading of those images
- If the image was loaded in the past, then put back the src on the img
- For every image that is downloaded, save its URL on localStorage

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the status of indexedDB is on the iPad, but this could be an alternative solution.

In short: Indexeddb is a clientside database. Data is stored in object stores which are key/value pairs. The maximum storage capacity is in theory the maximum of your disk space. For more information about indexeddb:

- [Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/)
- [My blog](http://www.kristofdegrave.be)

What you could do with the indexeddb:

When someone navigates to a page:

- Check every image tag if it is present in the indexeddb
- if present

  - Get the image from the indexeddb and put it in the image tag
- if not present

  - Download it
  - store it in the indexeddb
  - put the image in the image tag.

As extra (in the future) you can do as discribed by Sev: check the connetion type and only download the image when working on a fast internet connection.

Comment: Checkout PouchDB, an abstraction over multiple web persistent backends. That way you don't have to worry about the best approach for the visitor's browser.

Answer (score 0):

I have 'invented' a working solution developing a webapp on the iPad (iOS 6.0.x) that may answer your question.

The idea is first to check if a localstorage variable is set/defined or not yet (I use the title of the page, thus the webapp name.)

If this localstorage variable exists, then assume (in webapp sandbox context) that its the first time the app is being run. At this point I populate a UUID in conjunction with `$PHP_SESSION($uuid)` to avoid 'cross app contamination' in server-side PHP land.
In addition to this I have a dynamic manifest.appcache.php which includes in the CACHE section a list of files to add to the manifest. Thus;

```
<?
echo $manifest_file_list[0]."\n";
?>
```

Using the JS appcache manifest event listeners I then monitor the progress to something like `$('#manifestappcache').html(result);`